# Bitucket cloud - Curl payload request to trigger a pipeline

Tags: curl, bitbucket, cicd

I want to send a curl request to trigger a pipeline in one of the repositories we managed, the curl command is this, based on the api reference docs https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-pipelines/#trigger-a-custom-pipeline-with-variables

```
curl -X POST -is -u "$BITBUCKET_USERNAME":"$BITBUCKET_APP_PASSWORD" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/<workspace>/<repository>/pipelines/ \
--data '
  {
    "target": {
      "ref_type": "branch",
      "type": "pipeline_ref_target",
      "ref_name": "develop",
      "selector": {
        "type": "custom",
        "pattern": "Deploy to environment"
      }
    },
    "variables": [
      {
        "key": "NAMESPACE",
        "value": "xxx"
      },
      {
        "key": "URL",
        "value": "https://api.xx.xxx.net/"
      },
      {
        "key": "KID",
        "value": "xxxxx"
      }
    ],
    "WAIT": true
 }'
```

But I got this error

```
{"error": {"message": "Bad request", "detail": "bitbucket-pipelines.yml not found.", 
"data": {"key": "result-service.pipeline.yml-not-found", "arguments": {}}}}
```

It is like the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` wouldn't exist in the repository where I am trying to trigger the pipeline, but it does.
Could be that apparently, the payload I am providing on the curl command is incorrect in somehow according to what the bitbucket cloud API expects?

How can I get this curl request properly formed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. At the `selector` attribute, in the `pattern` sub key I had to provide the name of the existing pipeline on the `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file I want to be called to be executed on the request.

I was doing this

```
"selector": {
   "type": "custom",
   "pattern": "Deploy to environment"
 }
```

I need to do this

```
"selector": {
     "type": "custom", 
     "pattern": "<pipeline-name-to-be-called>"
}
```

Comment: As example, in the `pattern` field, if you have this kind of pipeline: https://bitbucket.org/blog/introducing-default-values-for-custom-pipeline-variables you should set the value to: "custom-name-and-region";